# Pygame lagging due to repeated looping, but don't know any alternative solution

Tags: python, pygame

In my game I want to make it so that whenever my mouse moves over slots in the player's inventory, an information window will pop up if there is an item in the slot. However, the only way I can think of to do this is to loop over all the inventory slot objects whenever the mouse cursor moves and check whether or not the x and y of the mouse cursor are inside the slot.

This is the code for whenever the mouse cursor moves to check if the cursor is within the inventory slot object (`if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION`):

```
for slot in self.inventory:
    if slot.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) and slot.item is not None:
    # show information window if True
    pass
```

Though this works, it makes the game lag whenever the mouse cursor moves due to the looping.

Is there any way I can do this kind of checking without going through each of the slots in the player's inventory?

Comment: Is the shape of the inventory fixed ? Are the boxes all of the same size ?

Comment: *"loop over all the inventory slot objects whenever the mouse cursor moves"* - How many object are on the screen? 10 or 20? This check won't make the game lag.

Comment: The boxes are all the same size, but they all have rects that hold their individual positions and their sizes so I don't think it matters. Hmm, I also checked just now and it seems that it doesn't lag with the checking itself - it's probably to do with the code after it then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

Whenever I moused over the slots, I wanted them to light up as well. It turns out that I was calling `pygame.image.load`every time I moved my mouse to do this. Changed it so that it was already pre-loaded and I was just switching between images instead, and the lag stopped.

Thanks again!